# "Join this community" button appears even though I've already joined

Tags: support, community, multiple-accounts

I have joined to a community Ask Ubuntu a couple of years ago, but this community doesn't appear in "My accounts" and within there is still the button "Join this community". Is my membership somehow expired, should I just join one more time (haven't tried to do so) or is there another way I should solve this? See the screenshots:

[image: message about me joining to the community AskUbuntu]

[image: The community isn't present in My accounts]

[image: The button "Join this community" still present]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *had* joined back in 2014. But you never did anything there, and your profile got [automatically deleted as inactive](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) (we've since disabled that feature). So you do need to join the community there, as you do not have a profile on the site.