# Link of "modified" should refers to answer in case of modification by deletion

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, deleted-answers

In case when user has deleted his answer the "modified" link on the main page [refers to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304093/join-this-community-button-appears-even-though-ive-already-joined) instead of to the deleted answer:

> [image: modified by deletion]

I think it should refers to the deleted post itself. Because users with 10k+ reputation can see deleted posts (and will be needed to scroll to the post), others will be redirected to the question in any case.

Seems that here is forgotten `?lastactivity` suffix for such links.

Comment: I believe this will "work" when there are non deleted answers in the question, according to the dev comment on my older bug report. :)